# $F$ entire with $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} F(z + N_{k}) = h(z)$ for every $h$ entire

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, entire-functions

**Universal Entire Functions.** Prove that there exists an entire function with the following "universal" property:

*Given any entire function $h$, there is an increasing sequence  $\{ N_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of positive integers such that* $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} F(z + N_{k}) = h(z)$$

Is Runge approximation theorem implicated ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a famous theorem by G. Birkhoff (1929):

G. Birkhoff, *Démonstration d'un théorème elémentaire sur les fonctions entiéres*, Cr. R.
Acad. Sci. Paris, **189** (1929), 473-475.

*Sketch of proof.* Let $\{p_j(z)\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be a dense (locally uniformly) sequence of polynomials in $\mathcal H(\mathbb C)$
and assume that each $p_j$ occurs infinitely often in this sequence.
Let $\{D_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of disjoint closed discs, each $D_j$ of radius
$j$, such that the centers $\{c_j\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ form an increasing sequence on the positive real
axis. Let $\{E_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of closed discs, each centered at the origin, such that $D_j \subset E_j$ and $D_{j+1} \cap E_j = \varnothing$.

Thus, $D_i\subset  E_j$ for $1 \le i \le j$ and
$D_i \cap E_j =\varnothing$, for $i \ge j + 1$.

Call $q_1 = q_1$. By [Runge's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem), there is a polynomial $q_2$, such that
$\|q_2\|_{E_1} < 1/2$ (here $\|f\|_K=\sup_{z\in K}|f(z)|$) and
$$
\big|q_2(z) - \big( p_2(z-c_2) - q_1(z)\big)\big| <1/2,
$$
on $D_2$. Next, choose a polynomial $q_3$, such that $\|q_3\|_{E_2} <\frac{1}{4}$, and
$$
\big|q_3(z) - \big(p_3(z- c_3) - q_1(z) - q_2(z)\big)\big| <\frac{1}{4},
$$
on $D_3$ In general, let $q_n$ be a polynomial, such that 
$\|q_n\|_{E_{n-1}} < \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ and
$$
\bigg|\,q_n(z) - \bigg(p_n(z - c_n) -
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}q_i(z)\bigg)\bigg|<\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},
$$
on $D_n$.

We shall show that the $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty q_n$ does what we want. 
It is readily seen that $f$ is
entire. It remains to show that if $g \in\mathcal  H(\mathbb C)$, and for $R > 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, 
arbitrary, then for some $j$; 
$$
|f(z + c_j) - g(z)| < 2, 
$$
whenever $|z|<  R$ 
In fact, it suffices to show this for $g=p$, where $p=p_k$, for some $k$. Noting
that there are infinitely many $k$, for which $p = p_k$, we can choose such a
large $k$ so that
$$
\bigg\|\,f - \sum_{i=1}^k q_i\,\bigg\|_{E_{k-1}}.
$$
Also,
$$
\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^k q_i(z) - p(z - c_k)\bigg| < \varepsilon,
$$
for all $z \in D_k$. In other words, for all $z \in D_k$, we have that
$$
|f(z) - p(z - c_k)| < 2\varepsilon,
$$ 
and the result follows by a change of variable.

Comment: Why can we choose $q_n$ which is very small but also approximates another polynomial?

Comment: Why we can choose $q_2$ such that $||q_2||_{E_1}<\frac{1}{2}$ and $||q_2(z)-(p_2(z-c_2)-q_1(z))||_{D_2} < \frac{1}{2}$ both at the same time?